# Retrieve information on stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am currenlty documenting all the stored procedures and functions within our database. I have created code to gather the names and parameters of the procedures however is it possible to retrieve information on what columns (if any) are returned?

I know there is a system procedure which can return this information however this is for an individual procedure where as i need it for all the procedures.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
SO.name AS [ObjectName],
SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType (UDF/SP)],
P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID],
P.name AS [ParameterName],
TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType],
P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID
FROM sys.objects
) 
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
GO
```

Does anyone know whether this is possible and if so how i could go about it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema],
so.object_id,
SO.name AS [ObjectName],
SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType (UDF/SP)],
P.parameter_id AS [ParameterID],
P.name AS [ParameterName],
TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id) AS [ParameterDataType],
P.max_length AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
P.is_output AS [IsOutPutParameter],
c.name as [ColumnName],
TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) AS [ColumnDataType],
c.max_length AS [ColumnMaxBytes]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID
FROM sys.objects
) 
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
GO
```

[image: My Results on My Database]

Comment: Not really that shows the input/output parameters whcih i already have however some of the procedures return a list of fields and records from a table. What i am after is a list of the columns each stored procedure returns (if any)

Comment: It also shows columns( INNER JOIN sys.parameters AS P
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS c) see my results that I added....

Comment: Sorry was did not scroll far enough apologies...this is absolutey perfect exactly what i wanted thank you very much